# Passing spring active profile to Spark App in EMR

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have developed a Spark App which is using Spring Boot and a Spark Job is submitted to EMR Cluster an EMR Cluster based on an Event.

This works as expected if the Spark app is not a Spring Boot App. With Spring Boot app we needed to change the way uber JAR Files are built.

How ever when we submit the job spring active profile is not getting passed correctly.

```html
spark-submit --verbose --master yarn --executor-memory 4g --class com.test.ConsoleApplication /home/hadoop/test.jar --driver-java-options='arg1 -Dspring.profiles.active=dev' --deploy-mode cluster --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dspring.profiles.active=dev" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"
```

What ever i do active profile is not getting passed and it is picking up the default "local" profile and running the spark app accordingly.

Converting Spark app to non-spring boot app is an option. But don't want to go that route unless there is no other option.

Thanks
Sateesh

Answer (score 1):

Able to resolve the issue by using bootstrap action on EMR Cluster. I am setting the environment variable to set the proper profile.

I am also able to pass using --conf option

```
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dspring.profiles.active=prod
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```